# Difference between assertRaises in a with versus statement for Unit Testing in Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am unit testing in python and I was told the with raises is the correct procedure versus the plain statement? Why is this?

```
def test_update(self):
   with self.assertRaises(object.api_call) as error:
         browser_update.fill_fields()
    self.assertEqual(error.exception.code, -1)
```

versus

```
def test_update(self):
    self.assertRaises(object.api_call, browser_update.fill_fields)
```

Comment: In case you want to capture the exception object and validate its properties.  See the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises